Event after Cache Clear
I couldn't find a event that is triggered after clearing the cache. Is there one that I didn't see or is there another way to execute a controller action after the cache is cleared? It only concerns the data cache.
Thanks in advance!

I found the event after a more thorough search. Every controller has the EVENT_AFTER_ACTION event, which is triggered after each action. The triggering action can be found with the id attribute on the event.
Event::on(
  UtilitiesController::class, 
  Controller::EVENT_AFTER_ACTION, 
  function (ActionEvent $event) {
    if ($event->action->id == 'clear-caches-perform-action') {
      //do your stuff
    }
  }
);

I didn't find a way to only listen to the clearing of the data cache. Feel free to add to my answer if you should know.
